# Is direct assignment valid to copy a pointer from array of pointers to another variable?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to copy an array of pointers to a new variable. I am not sure if the following direct assignment is the right way to perform the copy.

```
SVECTOR **features = (SVECTOR **) malloc(n*sizeof(SVECTOR *));
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    features[i] = getFeature();
}
SVECTOR **new_features = features; // Doubt: 1
SVECTOR *feature = features[0]; // Doubt: 2
```

Comment: It is correct, but remember that new_features and feature are only *copies* of the pointers, not of the objects that these point to. Also: it are aliased pointers: different pointers may point to the same objects (and do nasty things to these objects)

Comment: Are you hoping to copy all `n` pointers so that you have `2*n` pointers in the end? Or do you just want access to the `n` pointers via a second variable name?

Comment: @sarnold To be specific I need to access a sub-set of `n` pointers from a variable say `pos_features` and the rest from another variable say `neg_features`. Moreover, would want to get free `features` after copying to the new variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt 1 gives you an alias -- features and new_features reference the same array.
Attempt 2 gives you an alias to the first feature.

What you want, for a shallow copy (adequate if the values pointed to by the pointers returned by getFeature() are never modified or deallocated), is

```
SVECTOR **new_features = malloc(n * sizeof *features);
memcpy(new_features, features, n * sizeof *features);
```

If a shallow copy isn't adequate then you need to do a deep copy, which needs to know the structure of a feature:

```
SVECTOR **new_features = malloc(n * sizeof *features);
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    new_features[i] = cloneFeature(features[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, what if one needs to shallow copy only a subset of pointers from first array to the second.

Comment: @stressed_geek `new_feature[0] = feature[i]`, `new_feature[1] = feature[j]`, etc. If your arrays contain different numbers of features, then you should consider a structure containing the number of features and a pointer to them, e.g., `typedef struct { unsigned n; SVECTOR** features; } FeatureArray;` (although the name SVECTOR seems inappropriate for a feature).